# Difference between `Constraint Symbol` and `index_name` for Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, definition

The MySQL Syntax for Adding a Foreign Key in the Alter Table Command is as follows:

```
ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY [index_name] (index_col_name,...)
```

What is the difference between the `CONSTRAINT symbol` and the `index_name`. From what I can make out, they are both methods of naming a Foreign Key, but I figure there must be more differences that that, can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **[symbol]** is a constraint name, if it is specified, MySQL will create foreign key and index named as **[symbol]**; in this case **[index_name]** is ignored.

The second one **[index_name]** is index name. This index is created automatically. If **[symbol]** is omitted, the foreign key will be named by server, and index will be named as **[index_name]**.

Comment: So they are basically the same? If so, then which one should be used?

Comment: I use `CONSTRAINT [symbol]`, it names foreign key and its index.